# i can's access to the variable i posted to view from controller in laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel

i have laravel application.
i posted variable $res in my controller to my view and in the view i have no access to the variable i posted.
here is my code:

my route:

```
Route::get('/pickUpQuestion','createQuizController@showResult');
```

my controller:

```
public function showResult()
{
    $prio = Input::get('quiz_prio');

    $cat = Input::get('quiz_cat');

    $les = Input::get('quiz_less');

    $rdate = Input::get('date_start');

    $res = DB::select("select title from quiz where categories_id='$r2' and lesson_id='$r3' and priority_id='$r1' and date_start='$rdate'");

    return View::make('pickUpQuestion')->with('result',$res);
}
```

and my view:

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('content')

<?php
   var_dump($res);
?>
@stop
```

i take the values in my query from another form in a different view with post method to this view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mistake is with the function `with()`

The first parameter need to be the name of variable that will be use in view and the second parameter is the value of the first parameter.

The code should look like this

```
return View::make('pickUpQuestion')->with('res',$res);
```